# Confirming before proceeding through checking of services on multiple machines

Tags: powershell

My goal is to check the services on multiple remote machines to make sure they are running, and starting them if they are not. I would like to modify the below code to add the ability to ask the user before proceeding to the next $computerName, to display and confirm the status of group of $serviceNames that is being passed through the function.

In a text file servers.txt the contents are as follows:

```
server1-serviceA,ServiceB,ServiceC
server2-serviceD,ServiceE,ServiceF
server3-serviceG,ServiceH,ServiceI
```

And here is the powershell script, checking different services for each server using the split function

```
$textFile = Get-Content C:\temp\servers.txt

foreach ($line in $textFile) {

    $computerName = $line.split("-")[0]  #Getting computername by using Split
    $serviceNames = $line.split("-")[1]  #Getting Service names by using split

    foreach ($serviceName in $serviceNames.split(",")) {
        # Again using split to handle multiple service names

        try {
            Write-Host " Trying to start $serviceName in $computerName"
            Get-Service -ComputerName $computerName -Name $serviceName | Start-Service -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "SUCCESS: $serviceName has been started"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Failed to start $serviceName in $computerName"
        }
     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`PSHostUserInterface.PromptForChoice` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) for this, here is an example of how you can implement it:

```bash
# Clear this variable before in case it's already populated
$choice = $null

foreach ($line in $textFile) {
    $computerName = $line.split("-")[0]
    $serviceNames = $line.split("-")[1]

    # If previous choice was not equal to 2 (Yes to All), ask again
    if($choice -ne 2) {
        $choice = $host.UI.PromptForChoice(
            "my title here",                   # -> Title
            "Continue with: ${computerName}?", # -> Message
            @("&Yes", "&No", "Yes to &All"),   # -> Choices
            0                                  # -> Default Choice (Yes)
        )
    }
    # If choice was 1 (No), stop the script here
    if($choice -eq 1) { return }

    # Same logic here
}
```